# How to refactor getStaticProps and getStaticPaths to getServerSideProps in Next application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In code below

```
import Head from "next/head";

import { apiURL } from "../../helpers/api";

import DisplaySingleGame from "../../components/Games/DisplaySingleGame";

export default function singleGame({ dlc, game, screenshots, similar }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{game?.name}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={game?.name} />
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.ico" />
      </Head>
      <DisplaySingleGame
        dlc={dlc}
        game={game}
        screenshots={screenshots}
        similar={similar}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const results = await Promise.all([
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/screenshots?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/game-series?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/additions?`),
  ]);
  const [game, screenshots, similar, dlc] = results;

  if (!game || game.message) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      game: game || [],
      screenshots: screenshots?.results || [],
      similar: similar?.results || [],
      dlc: dlc?.results || [],
    },
    revalidate: 120,
  };
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await apiURL(`/games/lists/main?ordering=-rating&`);

  const paths = data?.results.map((item) => ({
    params: { name: item.name.toLowerCase() },
  }));

  return {
    paths: paths || [],
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}
```

I use the website API to display the catalog of games.
I'm experimenting with SSG and SSR in next.js . Right now I'm trying to rewrite the file from getStaticProps and getStaticPath to getServerSideProps but I'm getting errors.How would I refactor my code to make everything work?
2) If I change it on SSR, like this:

```
import Head from "next/head";

import { apiURL } from "../../helpers/api";

import DisplaySingleGame from "../../components/Games/DisplaySingleGame";

export default function singleGame({ dlc, game, screenshots, similar }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{game?.name}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={game?.name} />
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.ico" />
      </Head>
      <DisplaySingleGame
        dlc={dlc}
        game={game}
        screenshots={screenshots}
        similar={similar}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const results = await Promise.all([
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/screenshots?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/game-series?`),
    apiURL(`/games/${params.name}/additions?`),
  ]);
  const [game, screenshots, similar, dlc] = results;

  if (!game || game.message) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      game: game || [],
      screenshots: screenshots?.results || [],
      similar: similar?.results || [],
      dlc: dlc?.results || [],
    },
    revalidate: 120,
  };
};

// export async function getStaticPaths() {
//   const data = await apiURL(`/games/lists/main?ordering=-rating&`);

//   const paths = data?.results.map((item) => ({
//     params: { name: item.name.toLowerCase() },
//   }));

//   return {
//     paths: paths || [],
//     fallback: "blocking",
//   };
// }
```

It bring me next error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Eaf.png)

Comment: Getting rid of `getStaticPaths` completely, and renaming `getStaticProps` to `getServerSideProps` should be enough. Can you show us what your current `getServerSideProps` looks like, and the errors you're seeing?

Comment: I have edited the question. do you mean like this?

Comment: You also have to remove the `revalidate: 120` from the return statement - that's  specific to `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Can you please explain why we can just drop the getStaticPath function?

Comment: `getStaticPaths` is used for static generation (SSG) of dynamic pages to tell Next.js what paths should be generated at build time. When using `getServerSideProps` Next.js generates the pages on each request (SSR) so it doesn't need to know what paths to generate in advance.